# Issue about using md5() inbuilt function hashing in MySQL

Tags: mysql, hash, passwords, md5

I have a program where the users enters their `username` and `password` in 2 fields respectively. I store each password as a md5 hash in a MySQL table in two rows respectively (**although I know is not very secure)**. Instead of hashing the password when the users enters it and then comparing it to the database, I do the following:

```
select * from users
where username = 'value_from_the_username_field' AND
password  = 'md5(value_from_the_pass_field)'
```

I would like to ask is it true that the password would be visible in a plain text via the network ***before reaching the server and executing the query***  and how this could happen?(I could not understand the concept very well)

Comment: `md5()`is obsolete for hashing passwords and should *not be used*.

Comment: If you're concerned about sensitive information passing from a website to your PHP server, then you should be discussing things like SSL/HTTPS.  SSL is what protects something like a clear text password going from a webpage to a PHP server.  There isn't much point in what you are doing now, but at the same time, by itself this should not expose the password any more than what was already happening.

Answer (score 0):

To make this safe, you absolutely have to salt the password hashes, and then this problem will solve itself, because the database can't do the hashing.

Instead you need to call a password-hash function in your development language, like [password_hash()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) for PHP, and afterwards you insert the hash into the database.